# Size of execution enviroment of function in R

Tags: r, size, environment

How to get the size of a function's execution environment?
I tried to call `environment()` inside the function in order to get the current environment (which I assume should be the execution one) and pass it to `env.profile()`:

```
f <- function(x) {
    browser()
    env.profile(environment())
}

f()
```

Comment: `object.size(environment())`

Comment: @joel.wilson it will return 56 bytes regardless the size of the environment (if for instance one creates inside the function large vector).

Comment: so why don't we use `size = env.profile(environment())$size` ?

Comment: @joel.wilson it returns NULL (I had to state it before)